# Xamarin - Pass session to WebView from HttpClient

Tags: windows, session, webview, xamarin

I am using Xamarin to create a native Login screen for my web application.

The login view submits details, handshakes, and returns a success when login credentials are met. However, because the session cookie isn't stored on the phone's web view once I open the page it doesn't work.

Is there any way I can get the session cookie from the result of the HttpClient call and pass it to the Xamarin WebView. Can this be done in a common class or does it have to be device specific? And if it has to be device specific is there a way to do it for Windows Phone?

Any advice would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you return a token in your login method call and pass that to your webview?

Comment: Hi valdetero. Thanks for your reply. Yes I can. However is there a better method for this with WebView. I can pass it through the Query string of the source URL but was hoping for some thing more secure...

Comment: Hi, how did you go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in Windows Phone but I have a sessionId, which I pass to a JavaScript inside the source of the webview - I'm using a custom renderer then call the script on the webpage (the source of the WebView)

To achieve this setup a custom view and renderer.  Then in your renderer get the view and the sessionId property on the view:

```
protected override async void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if(e.PropertyName == SessionWebView.SessionIdProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        view = Element as SessionWebView;
        Control.LoadCompleted += Control_LoadCompleted;         
        if (view != null)
        {
            _currentSessionId = view.SessionId;
        }
    }
}
```

Then listed for the Load Complete and call the javascript function in your webview.

```
void Control_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!scriptCalled)
        {
            Control.IsScriptEnabled = true;
            var param = new string[1];
            param[0] = _currentSessionId;
            Control.InvokeScript("initWebView", param);
            scriptCalled = true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Not sure if there is a better way but this works for me in WindowsPhone.