# Share session between WebView and Soap Client in Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms, webview, asmx, session-state

I have a WebView that calls HTTP(S) websites and a SOAP client that calls .asmx WebService methods.

The WebService methods have attribute `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` and I need to use the same HttpSessionState for both WebView HTTP calls and WebService methods. How to do this?

What I need is to use some data obtained by a WebView HTTP request in a subsequent WebService call. Usually I would do this using the HttpSessionState.

**Edit**: What I can do is:

Before creating the WebView I can call a method in my WebService:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public HttpSessionState Init()
    {
        return this.Context.Session;
    }
```

But how can I use information of this result value to make WebView use the same HTTP session?

Comment: You can check this [Xamarin - Pass session to WebView from HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600824/xamarin-pass-session-to-webview-from-httpclient) for more information.